# jQuery - mouseenter works in chrome but not firefox

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of jQuery:

```
$('#list_cont').on('mouseenter', '.show_map', function() {
    $(this).next('.map_cont').stop().fadeIn(800);
}).on('mouseleave', '.show_map', function() {
    if (!$(this).next('.map_cont').is(':hover')) {
        $(this).next('.map_cont').delay(600).stop().fadeOut(800);
    }
});

$('#list_cont').on('mouseenter', '.show_map', function() {
    $(this).stop().show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.map_cont', function() {
    $(this).delay(600).stop().fadeOut(800);
});
```

It shows `.map_cont` on `.show_map` mouseenter, then if hovered on `.map_cont`, it doesn't fade out until cursor leaves `.map_cont`.

This works in chrome but not in Firefox.  I have no clue how to cross browser test this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.map_cont` is inside the `#list_cont`, it does so. So, you need to define your function this way:

```
$('.map_cont').on('mouseleave', '.show_map', function() {
    if (!$(this).next('.map_cont').is(':hover')) {
        $(this).next('.map_cont').delay(600).stop().fadeOut(800);
    }
});
```